# How can I create new project, OAuth key and P12 key in google console developer using Js/Java for google marketplace app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, google-api-client, google-apps-marketplace

My goal is to create a new project, generate 'Oauth key' and 'Service account key(p12 key)' in google developer console using JS/Java code for my google market place app. How can i achieve that?

Note: I want to make an app that will automate project creation and key creation when someone installs it from the marketplace. Right now I have to create a new project and a key manually for every new client that we onboard

Comment: can anyone suggest, whether is it even possible or not?

Comment: Please help me with any suggestion, clue or any link. I am not even sure about its feasibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For service account keys, you can use [the Google Identity and Access Management API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/). There is currently no public API for creating OAuth clients.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply.May you please suggest then how just other app ask permission for different-2 clients and directly allow them to use their services . I think they would have been creating new project in and OAuth and P12 automatically for every new user  in developer console and seperatly and somehow not manually ? your suggestion please